# Why does the author said "When $\mathcal{L}(E, F)$ is a Banach space, we can meaningfully speak of the continuity of the derivative"?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

I'm reading about the derivative in my analysis textbook:

> [image]

I could not understand why the author said that

> When $\mathcal{L}(E, F)$ is a Banach space, we can meaningfully speak of the continuity of the derivative.

IMHO, I usually do exercises about limits and continuity in metric spaces. On the other hand, $\mathcal{L}(E, F)$ is a metric space with the operator norm.

**My question:**

Is there any reason that the author said "When $\mathcal{L}(E, F)$ is a Banach space, we can meaningfully speak of the continuity of the derivative"?

Comment: I don't see any reason. Even if $L(E,F)$ is just a normed space, continuity is defined.

Comment: I suppose it simply means that we can ask whether $\partial f$ is continuous (which makes sense whether or not $L(E,F)$ is Banach), and that it is relevant. To take an analogy, you can talk about differentiating functions $\mathbb{Q\to Q}$, so it makes sense, but it's not relevant because $\mathbb Q$ is not complete  - here it's the same kind of thing : you can ask about continuity generally, but it won't be meaningful/relevant

Comment: @Max Define "relevant".

Comment: Hi @Max, please be more specific about "relevant" :)

Comment: @MadnessForMATH BTW, as far as I remember, you have that $L(E,F)$ is Banach if and only if $F$ is Banach. At least "$F$ Banach $\Rightarrow$ $L(E,F)$ Banach" is true.

Comment: Hi @amsmath, that's totally correct!

Comment: Well imagine a function $f:\mathbb{R\to R}$ such that $f(\mathbb Q)\subset \mathbb Q$, and such that $f'(0) = \sqrt 2$. Then you can restrict and corestrict $f$ to $\mathbb Q$, I'll keep the notation $f$ , and if you define the derivative "naively", you'll get that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ : but clearly you want it to be, because although the limit doesn't exist in $\mathbb Q$, it "should" exist (it does, in $\mathbb R$). That's the sort of thing that completeness avoids, and I suppose it works the same for vector spaces

Comment: @Max Then you can degrade every non-complete normed space to "not relevant" when it comes to limits.

Comment: However, the sentence in the book suggests that when $F$ is not complete, we cannot talk about continuous differentiability in a "meaningful" way. In other words: continuous differentiability is not well-defined then. But this is not true. The sentence should therefore be reformulated or deleted.

Comment: @amsmath in a sense, non-complete spaces are not where you should be looking at limits, because some are missing (I don't necessarily agree, but it is arguable, and in some contexts it makes sense). And mostly, I'm saying that because I think that's what the authors meant by "meaningful" (or something along those lines). For instance, complete spaces are where you can integrate stuff easily, and integration and derivation are related

Comment: @Max I don't agree. Not even with your interpretation of the sentence. "meaningful" in maths means "well-defined".

Comment: @amsmath : no, "meaningful" can have other meanings when you're talking heuristically or not precisely (which is clearly the case here, given that of course you can always discuss continuity). "Not meaningful" can mean "it's not an interesting notion". But it's no use debating this (the arguments will be "I don't agree" and "Many people use it that way")

Comment: @Max "But it's no use debating this (the arguments will be "I don't agree" and "Many people use it that way")" You're smart. Exactly those would've been my next words. ;-) Never mind...

Comment: I suspect the author says that because the author is interested in developing the theory in the confines of Banach spaces, where completeness provides a rich theory with powerful results. It is that theory that is "meaningful" to the author at this time and in this context. It is not meant to be a slight or a dismissal of the larger-but-less-powerful theory of normed spaces in general, but just an indication of where the author's focus is.